Java Scanner not Working in Textpad, Compiles Without errors but stuck loading
When running a prgoram with scanner in textpad it compiles without error but when running just keeps loading until interrrupted then gives exit code 130
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab3 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        double Sales;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the total company sales in millions to 2 decimals: ");
        Sales = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(Sales);

        double EastCoastSales = (Sales*0.62);

        System.out.println("The East Coast division made "+EastCoastSales+" million in sales");
    }
}


this is the code im trying to run, when I interrupt it itll print the first line there but thats all otherwise its just loading on a blank window
I've tried copying the teachers examples or other examples online and getting them to run however the reult is the same, it loads forever then when you interrupt it prints the println below Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in) then exits with code 130

There's nothing wrong with your code. Your java install is broken (unlikely), you've misconfigured textpad (likely), or textpad is not capable of doing this because it doesn't offer a full terminal (possible). Use another editor or configure it differently.

Have you tried entering a double? It's worth noting that System.out is buffered System.out.print does not automatically clear the buffer. Option 1: Add System.out.flush(); after System.out.print("Please enter the total company sales in millions to 2 decimals: "); Option 2: Use System.out.println("Please enter the total company sales in millions to 2 decimals: "); passing a \n (or using println) includes an automatic flush.
